# URL aliases without Drupal

Tags: url

How can I implement URL aliases in my website if I am not using Drupal? Is there any plugin to help me in this?

Comment: This question is awfully vague. What do you mean by "URL aliases"? What does Drupal have to do with anything?

Comment: It's not vague if you know about Drupal (as mentioned by the title, text and tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Apache's **[mod_rewrite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine)** with an .htaccess file to implement friendly urls without Drupal. You will also need at least a script to redirect from the url handler to the actual contents however.

[Example here](http://codecanyon.net/item/mod-rewriter/79439?ref=wildpeaks) (or [if your server doesn't support mod_rewrite](http://codecanyon.net/item/mod-rewrite-simulator-php-mod_rewrite/88186?ref=wildpeaks))